# Unable to pass BSTR pointer to a COM object with Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, com, ole, bstr

In my Python program, I am trying to make a call to a custom COM object written in C++. The function I'm trying to call is constructed like this:

```
void foo(
BSTR *pbstrParameters,
BSTR *pbtrResult
);
```

It is my understanding that Python converts unicode strings to BSTR variants when passing to COM objects. Perfect! That's what my function is expecting. Theoretically, I should be able to make the call like this:

```
COMobject.foo("string1","string2")
```

But that results in a type mismatch error: `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)`

Next, I tried passing it actual BSTRs from the comtypes module:

`COMobject.foo(comtypes.BSTR("string1"),comtypes.BSTR("string2"))`, but that also resulted in a Type mismatch.

Lastly, I tried passing pointers to BSTRs, as defined in the comtypes `_ctype_to_vartype` dictionary.

```
COMobject.foo(POINTER(BSTR),POINTER(BSTR))
```

Which results in the error: `TypeError: Objects of type '_ctypes.PyCPointerType' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT`

If I can't convert `POINTER(BSTR)` to a COM variant, then what is this line in the comtypes' `_ctype_to_vartype` dict in automation.py for?:

```
POINTER(BSTR): VT_BYREF|VT_BSTR,
```

Comment: Your function foo doesn't take a BSTR, it takes a pointer to a BSTR. (Where a BSTR is itself a pointer, but that's not particularly relevant here).

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have edited the title.

Comment: The C/C++ definition is not always sufficient to determine how to call it/ Do you have an .idl file? or a .tlb?